# iPhone: create animating UITextField in UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, uitextfield, uinavigationbar

Does anyone know how to create a UITextField similar to the 'Google' search field in the iPhone Safari App? The bar when clicked, animates to fill up the entire NavigationBar & add a cancel button?

Thanks,